# Oracle registry entry not created after installing 12C client 32 bit

Tags: oracle, registry, oracle12c

After having Oracle 12C client 32-bit installed on a VM, I found that the environment variable path was created but there is no registry entry for Oracle in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE.

As I understand it, this should be created automatically during install and since the environment variable path exists and is correct, I'd expect to find the registry entry.

Any thoughts on why this wouldn't have been created and, without uninstalling/reinstalling, how I can go about manually creating it?

The reason I am avoiding the reinstallation route is because this has happened previously on a different machine, and reinstalling did not fix the issue.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

For (any) 32-bit application you have to check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Oracle`

When a **32-bit** application access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` then it is automatically redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`. Actually that's a simplified statement, see [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

A 64-bit application has access to both.

See also [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get a general description.